# BLE stops working with GKI_exception getbuf: out of buffers

Tags: android, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy

I develop an app for Android Lollipop (phone) that receives data from portable device using BLE. 
The data from device is tranmistted via notifications. 
Notifications cause onCharacteristicChanged() method where the data is parsed and saved into file.

Everything may work fine for few hours. But at some random time it stops working and the log is filled by the following messages:

```
...
07-27 00:36:33.940 E/bt-l2cap(31622): l2cu_build_header - no buffer
07-27 00:36:33.989 E/GKI_LINUX(31622): GKI_exception(): Task State Table
07-27 00:36:33.989 E/GKI_LINUX(31622): TASK ID [0] task name [BTU] state [1]
07-27 00:36:33.989 E/GKI_LINUX(31622): TASK ID [1] task name [BTIF] state [1]
07-27 00:36:33.989 E/GKI_LINUX(31622): TASK ID [2] task name [A2DP-MEDIA] state [1]
07-27 00:36:33.989 E/GKI_LINUX(31622): GKI_exception 65524 getbuf: out of buffers
...
```

And then by some reasons this GKI_exception messages stop with the following line:

```
07-27 01:32:23.361 E/bt-btm  (31622): btm_sec_disconnected - Clearing Pending flag
```

And after that BLE will never connect to the device until we turn BLE off and on at the phone.

How to solve it?

Comment: Search the Android bug tracker.  I think there is something there relating to this.

Comment: I think I've localized the issue. 
When I've reworked the code and left only one instance of the service responsible for maintaining BLE connection and left only one GATT active at a time - the issue has gone. 
I think in my previous version of code, every time I've disconnected and reconnected to the GATT - it created an additional instance. 

Another part of rework is that i've added a code watching over "connecting time". If it exceeds max level (i've set 3 seconds) then i turn off and turn on BLE. This solves the cases when a phone stopped connecting to device even when it is available.